# TextToSpeech in JAPANESE language in Japan

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech, cjk

Knowing that the JAPANESE language is not supported by TextToSpeech on Android (Kotlin), I wonder if I missed something or **how are Japanese developers doing?**

I would be very grateful for any idea that will tell me the turn around so that I can use this language and TexteToSpeech and not in .mp3.

```
...
if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // set the language for tts
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.JAPAN)

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                showTheToast("Japanese not supported!")
                Log.e("TTS", "Japanese is not supported! :-(")
            } else {
                tts!!.setSpeechRate(1.0f)
            }
        } else {
            showTheToast("The initialization failed!")
        }
...
```

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Japanese should be supported since android 1.5 (API Level 4)

Comment: I know that but why it is refused ? My goal is to make it say different expressions written in Japanese so that they are pronounced correctly and not with an American or Spanish accent. This for example: "あ り が と う ご ざ い ま し た". Do you want my complete code for tts ?

Comment: Oh, I just discovered now that it works the first time it is called and never after and that on the emulator Pixel 4 API 25 and on my Samsung A50 !? Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on Android sorry.
I saw now that it need to install the language we want for tts with Google Engine. That's the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Locale.JAPAN` to `"ja_JP"`.
It works for me.